# php: dynamically generating JNLP?

Tags: php, jnlp

how can I dynamically generate a .jnlp file ? Is there a mime-type that needs to be specified for this extension ?

Comment: A file containing Java Web Start information - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [german version](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start#Java_Network_Launching_Protocol_.28JNLP.29) of the [Wikipedia Article on JLNP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start#Java_Network_Launching_Protocol_.28JNLP.29), the content type is

```
 application/x-java-jnlp-file
```

you'll presumably need to send that.

Other than that, it should be just sending the XML data.